# Gosseract not run

Tags: go, ocr

**# github.com/otiai10/gosseract/v2
tessbridge.cpp:5:10: fatal error: leptonica/allheaders.h: No such file or directory
5 | #include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.**

below is the code i wrote

it gives an error. I reinstalled Tesseract-i, it still gives the same error

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/otiai10/gosseract/v2"
)

func main() {

    client := gosseract.NewClient()

    defer client.Close()

    client.SetImage("C:\\Users\\labusers\\Downloads\\khan.png")

    text, _ := client.Text()
    fmt.Println(text)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing Tesseract can be tricky. The following Dockerfile works:

```
FROM golang:1.14.9

RUN cat /etc/os-release
# Output: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
RUN apt-get -qy update

RUN apt-get install -qy libleptonica-dev libtesseract-dev
RUN apt-get install -qy libtool m4 automake cmake pkg-config
RUN apt-get install -qy libicu-dev libpango1.0-dev libcairo-dev

RUN cd /opt && git clone https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract
WORKDIR /opt/tesseract
RUN git reset --hard 4.1.1
RUN ./autogen.sh &&\
    ./configure --enable-debug LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"
RUN make -j 8
RUN make install && ldconfig
RUN tesseract --version

ENV TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/local/share/tessdata
ENV TESSDATA_REPO=https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best
WORKDIR ${TESSDATA_PREFIX}
RUN wget -q ${TESSDATA_REPO}/raw/4.1.0/eng.traineddata
```

The Dockerfile build Tesseract from source so you can choose Tesseract version. I wrote this Dockerfile when I used `gosseract` library 2 years ago.

Comment: thank you @Tùng Đào Thanh Tùng